# selects dinamicos con javascript

Tags: javascript

Necesito crear 3 select, por ejemplo uno que contenga areas, otro que contenga categorias y por ultimo uno que tenga subcategorias, al seleccionar una area se deben cargar las categorias de dicha area y al seleccionar una de esas categorias se deben cargar en el tercer select las subcategorias de dicha categoria. Hasta el momento tengo solo dos y los tome de un ejemplo que hay en la pagina, pero no logro enlazar el tercer select. Les agradezco la ayuda.

El codigo HTML es:

```
<table>
                    <tr>
                        <td align=right>Provincia:</td>
                        <td align=left colspan=3>
                            <!-- Añadido onchange para cargar los pueblos -->
                            <select name="provincia" id="provincia" onchange="cargarPueblos();">
                                <!-- Hay que terminar los options -->
                                <!-- 
                                    Eliminado de value la llamada a la función,
                                    si eso funciona lo desconocía, y aunque 
                                    lo haga es totalmente innecesario, 
                                    lo correcto es usar el evento onchange 
                                    -->
                                <option value="">Seleccione una Provincia...</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>                    
                        <td align=right>Pueblo:</td>
                        <td align=left colspan=3>
                            <select name="pueblo" id="pueblo" onchange="cargarCantones();">
                                <!-- Hay que terminar los options -->
                                <!-- 
                                    Eliminado de value la llamada a la función,
                                    si eso funciona lo desconocía, y aunque 
                                    lo haga es totalmente innecesario, 
                                    lo correcto es usar el evento onchange 
                                    -->
                                <option value="">Seleccione un Pueblo...</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>                    
                        <td align=right>Canton:</td>
                        <td align=left colspan=3>
                            <select name="canton" id="canton">
                                <!-- Hay que terminar los options -->
                                <!-- 
                                    Eliminado de value la llamada a la función,
                                    si eso funciona lo desconocía, y aunque 
                                    lo haga es totalmente innecesario, 
                                    lo correcto es usar el evento onchange 
                                    -->
                                <option value="">Seleccione un canton...</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
</table>
```

Y el codigo javascript que tengo es:

```
function cargarProvincias() {
    var array = ["Cantabria", "Asturias", "Galicia", "Andalucia", "Extremadura"];
    array.sort();
    addOptions("provincia", array);
}


//Función para agregar opciones a un <select>.
function addOptions(domElement, array) {
    var selector = document.getElementsByName(domElement)[0];
    for (provincia in array) {
        var opcion = document.createElement("option");
        opcion.text = array[provincia];
        // Añadimos un value a los option para hacer mas facil escoger los pueblos
        opcion.value = array[provincia].toLowerCase()
        selector.add(opcion);
    }
}



function cargarPueblos() {
    // Objeto de provincias con pueblos
    var listaPueblos = {
      cantabria: ["Laredo", "Gama", "Solares", "Castillo", "Santander"],
      asturias: ["Langreo", "Villaviciosa", "Oviedo", "Gijon", "Covadonga"],
      galicia: ["Tui", "Cambados", "Redondella", "Porriño", "Ogrove"],
      andalucia: ["Dos Hermanas", "Écija", "Algeciras", "Marbella", "Sevilla"],
      extremadura: ["Caceres", "Badajoz", "Plasencia", "Zafra", "Merida"]
    }

    var provincias = document.getElementById('provincia')
    var pueblos = document.getElementById('pueblo')
    var provinciaSeleccionada = provincias.value

    // Se limpian los pueblos
    pueblos.innerHTML = '<option value="">Seleccione un Pueblo...</option>'

    if(provinciaSeleccionada !== ''){
      // Se seleccionan los pueblos y se ordenan
      provinciaSeleccionada = listaPueblos[provinciaSeleccionada]
      provinciaSeleccionada.sort()

      // Insertamos los pueblos
      provinciaSeleccionada.forEach(function(pueblo){
        let opcion = document.createElement('option')
        opcion.value = pueblo
        opcion.text = pueblo
        pueblos.add(opcion)
      });
    }

  }

 // Iniciar la carga de provincias solo para comprobar que funciona
cargarProvincias();
```

Answer (score 3):

Tomando el enunciado de tu pregunta en el que indicas que deseas tener tres selects area, categoria, subcategoria te muestro una solución:

```js
var areas = [
  {id:1,name:"area1"},
  {id:2,name:"area2"},
  {id:3,name:"area3"}
]

var categorias = [
  {id:1,name:"categoria1",idArea:1},
  {id:2,name:"categoria2",idArea:1},
  {id:3,name:"categoria3",idArea:1},
  {id:4,name:"categoria4",idArea:2},
  {id:5,name:"categoria5",idArea:2},
  {id:6,name:"categoria6",idArea:2},
  {id:7,name:"categoria7",idArea:3},
  {id:8,name:"categoria8",idArea:3},
  {id:9,name:"categoria9",idArea:3},
]

var subCategorias = [
  {id:1,name:"subcategoria1",idCategoria:1},
  {id:2,name:"subcategoria2",idCategoria:1},
  {id:3,name:"subcategoria3",idCategoria:2},
  {id:4,name:"subcategoria4",idCategoria:2},
  {id:5,name:"subcategoria5",idCategoria:3},
  {id:6,name:"subcategoria6",idCategoria:3},
  {id:7,name:"subcategoria7",idCategoria:4},
  {id:8,name:"subcategoria8",idCategoria:4},
  {id:9,name:"subcategoria9",idCategoria:5},
  {id:10,name:"subcategoria10",idCategoria:5},
  {id:11,name:"subcategoria11",idCategoria:6},
  {id:12,name:"subcategoria12",idCategoria:6},
  {id:13,name:"subcategoria13",idCategoria:7},
  {id:14,name:"subcategoria14",idCategoria:7},
  {id:15,name:"subcategoria15",idCategoria:8},
  {id:16,name:"subcategoria16",idCategoria:8},
  {id:17,name:"subcategoria17",idCategoria:9},
  {id:18,name:"subcategoria18",idCategoria:9},
]

//creando los options de area
var areasSelect = document.getElementById('areas');
var categoriasSelect = document.getElementById('categorias');
var subCategoriasSelect = document.getElementById('subCategorias');

areasSelect.addEventListener("change", cargarCategorias);
categoriasSelect.addEventListener("change", cargarSubCategorias); 

areas.forEach(function(area){
  let opcion = document.createElement('option')
  opcion.value = area.id
  opcion.text = area.name
  areasSelect.add(opcion)
})

function cargarCategorias(){
  categoriasSelect.options.length = 1;
  subCategoriasSelect.options.length = 1;
  categorias
  .filter(function (categoria){
      return categoria.idArea == this;
  }, areasSelect.value)
  .forEach(function(categoria){
    let opcion = document.createElement('option')
    opcion.value = categoria.id
    opcion.text = categoria.name
    categoriasSelect.add(opcion);
  });
}

function cargarSubCategorias(){
   subCategoriasSelect.options.length = 1;
   subCategorias
  .filter(function (subCategoria){
      return subCategoria.idCategoria == this;
  }, categoriasSelect.value)
  .forEach(function(subCategoria){
    let opcion = document.createElement('option')
    opcion.value = subCategoria.id
    opcion.text = subCategoria.name
    subCategoriasSelect.add(opcion);
  });
}
```

```html
<label for="areas">Areas:</label>
<select id="areas">
  <option value="0">seleccione</option>
</select>
<br>

<label for="areas">Categorias:</label>
<select id="categorias">
  <option value="0">selecccione</option>
</select>
<br>

<label for="areas">Sub Categorias:</label>
<select id="subCategorias">
  <option value="0">selecccione</option>
</select>
```

**Explicando varias cosas:**

- Tenemos 3 variables que contienen la data de cada uno de los selects: areas, categorias y subcategorias. Las tres son arrays que contienen objetos, "areas" contiene objetos que indican el id y nombre; "categorias" contiene objetos que indican id, nombre y idArea (id del area al que pertenece la categoria); por último subCategorias tiene objetos que indican id, nombre y idCategoria (id de la categoria a la que pertenece la sub categoria). Esto nos va a servir para saber qué datos se deben mostrar dependiendo de cada opción seleccionada ya que necesitamos tener en los datos cómo se relacionan entre ellos.
- En el primer forEach simplemente se crean las opciones para el primer select "areas" ya que éste no depende de ningún otro.
- cargarCategorias y cargarSubCategorias colocan los select con lentgh 1 para que nada más quede la primera opción, es decir, "seleccione" creada directamente en el html ya luego se agregan las demás.
- Uso la función filter para filtrar (valga la redundancia) los elementos del array categorias donde el idArea sea el value de la opción seleccionada del select "areas" (areasSelect.value). Si te fijas en la función que usa filter uso "this" que es el valor del segundo parámetro que se le pasa a la función filter (areasSelect.value). Puedes ver más sobre ésto en: [Javscript filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter). Luego ya es crear los elementos en base a las categorias que quedaron filtradas. Funciona de igual manera en cargarSubCategorias.

Comment: Muchas garcias, pero ahora me surgio otro problema, yo agregue este select a un formulario de laravel y necesito poder guardarlo en la base de datos, la base de datos es en mysql, como lo podria lograr?

Comment: En ése caso debes formular otra pregunta donde coloques cómo tienes ahora todo y además se muestre la parte de laravel, así te podrán ayudar más personas.